# How do I detect that an iOS app is running on a jailbroken phone?

Tags: ios, iphone, jailbreak

If I want my app to behave differently on a jailbroken iPhone, how would I go about determining this?

Comment: You are going to be following a moving target, but you might try following the progress of these resources to see how effective your technique is: - https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Bypassing_Jailbreak_Detection
- https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/XCon

Answer (score 94, accepted):

It depends what you mean by jailbreak.  In the simple case, you should be able to see if Cydia is installed and go by that - something like

```
NSString *filePath = @"/Applications/Cydia.app";
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath])
{
   // do something useful
}
```

For hacked kernels, it's a little (lot) more involved.

Comment: Wouldn't it be enough to look for _any_ file/dir outside your sandbox? Like /etc?

Comment: Note that not all users have Cydia installed -- this is not a good check, and you should rather check for something like /bin/bash that /all/ users /will/ have.

Comment: Where does apt store its info? Or could I just call a system() command and find out. I want to find out if they have certain apps, and if they have them, then restrict the app

Comment: @chpwn is var/cache/apt a jailbreak only folder, and would that be a good check? Because when I check for bin/bash, even non-jailbreak devices register as jailbroken.

Comment: @RazorSharp At this point, almost all users do have Cydia. It's probably enough to check for that now. However, if you want a 100% reliable check, you'll want to use a kernel-based check as below.

Comment: regarding to bash check - see my answer below

Comment: FWIW the file checks are trivial to bypass. One can use mobilesubstrate to hook `fileExistsAtPath:` and make it return `NO` for the specific path you check.

Comment: Apple approved your app which contains the above code ?

Comment: This is not workable on xCon , Can advice more on how to do it.

https://github.com/masbog/isJB/issues/1 have more indepth code than above but still fails for xCon , any leads.

Comment: what is Cydia.app ? Please some one explain

Answer (score 61):

This is a code that combine some answers I found for this need, and will give you much higher success rate :

```
BOOL isJailbroken()
{
#if !(TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR)

   if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:@"/Applications/Cydia.app"] ||
       [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:@"/Library/MobileSubstrate/MobileSubstrate.dylib"] ||
       [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:@"/bin/bash"] ||
       [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:@"/usr/sbin/sshd"] ||
       [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:@"/etc/apt"] ||
       [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:@"/private/var/lib/apt/"] ||
       [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"cydia://package/com.example.package"]])  {
         return YES;
   }

   FILE *f = NULL ;
   if ((f = fopen("/bin/bash", "r")) ||
      (f = fopen("/Applications/Cydia.app", "r")) ||
      (f = fopen("/Library/MobileSubstrate/MobileSubstrate.dylib", "r")) ||
      (f = fopen("/usr/sbin/sshd", "r")) ||
      (f = fopen("/etc/apt", "r")))  {
         fclose(f);
         return YES;
   }
   fclose(f);

   NSError *error;
   NSString *stringToBeWritten = @"This is a test.";
   [stringToBeWritten writeToFile:@"/private/jailbreak.txt" atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
   [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:@"/private/jailbreak.txt" error:nil];
   if(error == nil)
   {
      return YES;
   }

#endif

   return NO;
}
```

Comment: this is much better than others, but I will not try to write text files, this will slow down the performance.

Comment: @Porizm, this is just a combination off some answers I found. Some of them didn't work for me, but worked for others.. so with this code you don't take chances.. If you use this you can be 99% sure. Regarding the performance, you can run it only once at each run and save the answer somewhere, You don't have to run it each time..

Comment: @yossi  and porizm apple approved your app which contains the above code ? please reply

Comment: This method should be an inlined C function, *not* Objective-C.  It's too easy to discover and bypass Objective-C methods, especially if you call it `isJailbroken`

Comment: @Yossi does this cover devices jailbroken using Taig?

Comment: @Lakshay I don't know.. You are more than invited to check and add here an answer :)

Comment: Checking if the device can open `cydia://package/com.example.package` will provide a false-positive if the user has an app installed that conforms to `cydia://` scheme like InstantTV.

Answer (score 53):

```
+(BOOL)isJailbroken {
    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"cydia://package/com.example.package"];
    return [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url];
}
```

Checking the file path `/Applications/Cydia.app` is not allowed on a normal phone? I've never heard of Apple detecting this and rejecting an app for it, but Apple is unpredictable. Cydia has [a URL scheme cydia://](http://handleopenurl.com/scheme/cydia)  which can be legally checked with UIApplication `canOpenURL:`

Comment: This is a great way to check, and it does not go outside your sandbox. Sure, if the jailbreaker does not have Cydia installed, it will return NO, but I think most Jailbreaks install Cydia.

Comment: can this string not be altered when the app is cracked?

Comment: For iOS9.0+ you also need to add LSApplicationQueriesSchemes key in app plist. Otherwise canOpenURL will always return false.

Comment: This will provide a false-positive if the user has an app installed that conforms to cydia:// scheme like InstantTV.

Comment: @thattyson thanks! I was looking to check why I was getting false positives

Answer (score 52):

Checking if the kernel is broken isn't THAT much more involved.

Jailbreaking makes the kernel's signature check of signed code always report that code is signed correctly, unbroken phones cannot run code with a bad signature.

So, include a separate executable in the app with a bad signature. It could just be a 3-line program that has main() and a return value. Compile the executable without code signing (turn it off in Project Settings->Build) and sign it with a different key using the "codesign" commandline utility.

Have your app exec the separate executable. If your program can't get the return value when running the separate executable with the bad sig, it's definitely jailed. If the separate executable returns A-OK, the phone is definitely jailbroken.

Comment: Can you get a (sub-)executable whose signature is invalid like that through the App Store?

Comment: Perhaps things have changed but wouldn't executing a separate executable prevent you from being approved to the app store?

Comment: Can someone answer on previous to comments? This is important questions.

Comment: Nobody is really going to stop you from writing a Mach-O to disk with an invalid signature. However, I disagree with the answer that checking that the kernel is broken isn't involved or that this is a definitive check by any means.

Answer (score 20):

```
BOOL isJailbroken()
{
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
    return NO;
#else
    FILE *f = fopen("/bin/bash", "r");

    if (errno == ENOENT)
    {
        // device is NOT jailbroken
        fclose(f);
        return NO;
    }
    else {
        // device IS jailbroken
        fclose(f);
        return YES;
    }
#endif
}
```

Comment: That's a good solution, but xCon and other tools like it can easily bypass this check. So, I'm looking for a better solution.

Comment: @AlexeiRobsky there is no perfect solution. There will always be someone who will find a way to bypass your protection, it's just a fact.

Answer (score 16):

I reworked in Swift 2.3 the solution provided by @Yossi

```
public static func jailbroken(application: UIApplication) -> Bool {
    guard let cydiaUrlScheme = NSURL(string: "cydia://package/com.example.package") else { return isJailbroken() }
    return application.canOpenURL(cydiaUrlScheme) || isJailbroken()
}


static func isJailbroken() -> Bool {

    if isSimulator {
        return false
    }

    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    if fileManager.fileExistsAtPath("/Applications/Cydia.app") ||
        fileManager.fileExistsAtPath("/Library/MobileSubstrate/MobileSubstrate.dylib") ||
        fileManager.fileExistsAtPath("/bin/bash") ||
        fileManager.fileExistsAtPath("/usr/sbin/sshd") ||
        fileManager.fileExistsAtPath("/etc/apt") ||
        fileManager.fileExistsAtPath("/usr/bin/ssh") {
        return true
    }

    if canOpen("/Applications/Cydia.app") ||
        canOpen("/Library/MobileSubstrate/MobileSubstrate.dylib") ||
        canOpen("/bin/bash") ||
        canOpen("/usr/sbin/sshd") ||
        canOpen("/etc/apt") ||
        canOpen("/usr/bin/ssh") {
        return true
    }

    let path = "/private/" + NSUUID().UUIDString
    do {
        try "anyString".writeToFile(path, atomically: true, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        try fileManager.removeItemAtPath(path)
        return true
    } catch {
        return false
    }
}

static func canOpen(path: String) -> Bool {
    let file = fopen(path, "r")
    guard file != nil else { return false }
    fclose(file)
    return true
}
```

Comment: you done good job, but if you comment on those url's we can appreciate.

Comment: `canOpen(path: ... `where you used and what is it mean.

Comment: Your code was not working in latest Xcode versions, can you update it. Thank you.

Answer (score 14):

You can detect if a device is JailBroken or not by checking for the following:

- Cydia is installed
- Verify some of the system paths
- Perform a sandbox integrity check
- Perform symlink verification
- Verify whether you create and write files outside your Sandbox

There is an open source library I created from various articles and books. [Try it out on GitHub](https://github.com/sat2eesh/ios-jailBroken)!

Answer (score 6):

The most sophisticated method I know is using `objc_copyImageNames()` function. It returns a list of currently loaded libraries and since most people have MobileSubstrate on jailbroken devices and most iAP crack tools depend on it, at least some MobileSubstrate libraries will show up.

Comment: Do you have any links on what MobileSubstrate/CydiaSubstrate libraries look like?   I don't have a jailbroken phone to play around with so am driving "blind" and Google searches basically come up with your comment above.

Comment: @chadbag I don't have one either but you can look for the `deb` file of MobileSubstrate, unpack it and blacklist (almost) all `.dylib`'s it packed.

Comment: Thanks, I got some code figured out and I may add in some more stuff based on your comment.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Please use following code for Swift 4 and above:
Add the following code in the appdelegate:

```
private func getJailbrokenStatus() -> Bool {
    if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR != 1 {
        // Check 1 : existence of files that are common for jailbroken devices
        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: "/Applications/Cydia.app")
            || FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: "/Library/MobileSubstrate/MobileSubstrate.dylib")
            || FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: "/bin/bash")
            || FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: "/usr/sbin/sshd")
            || FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: "/etc/apt")
            || FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: "/private/var/lib/apt/")
            || UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string:"cydia://package/com.example.package")!) {
            return true
        }
        // Check 2 : Reading and writing in system directories (sandbox violation)
        let stringToWrite = "Jailbreak Test"
        do {
            try stringToWrite.write(toFile:"/private/JailbreakTest.txt", atomically:true, encoding:String.Encoding.utf8)
            //Device is jailbroken
            return true
        } catch {
            return false
        }
    }
    else {
        return false
    }
}
```

Inside Appdelegate methods, write code as below

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive (_ application: UIApplication) {
    
    if getJailbrokenStatus() {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: LocalizedKeys.Errors.jailbreakError, message: LocalizedKeys.Errors.jailbreakErrorMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
        let jailBrokenView = UIViewController()
        
        jailBrokenView.view.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
        jailBrokenView.view.backgroundColor = .white
        self.window?.rootViewController = jailBrokenView
        jailBrokenView.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        if !UIScreen.main.isCaptured {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.blockImageView.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: self.blockImageView.removeFromSuperview() getting error, please suggest what to be done

Answer (score 4):

I am not aware of any "APIs" that exist for this.  If there were, then a jailbreak-masking product would quickly cover them up.

As lots of people point out, it is a cat-and-mouse game. And after both players become expert, it all comes down to who gets the first move. (Person holding the device.)

I found many good suggestions for detecting jailbreak in Zdziarski's new book "Hacking and Securing iOS Apps".  (Personally, I paid more for the O'Reilly eBook because they permit copy-and-paste.)

No, I am not affiliated with the publishers.  But I did find it a good book. I don't like to just publish hackers' mistakes so they can fix them, so I thought I'd point to the book.

Answer (score 4):

Try executing unsigned code through your application.

A jailbroken devices usually has the following characteristics:

- run unsigned code
- has Cydia installed
- has jailbreak files
- full r/w access to the whole filesystem
- some system files will have been modified (content and so sha1 doesn't match with original files)
- stuck to specific version (jailbreakable version)

Just checking file existence for jailbreak detection is doomed to fail.
These checks are easy to bypass.

Comment: Trying to execute unsigned code would make your app being rejected from the appstore

Answer (score 4):

Some common files to check for:
`/Library/MobileSubstrate/MobileSubstrate.dylib`

`/Applications/Cydia.app`

`/var/cache/apt`

`/var/lib/apt`

`/var/lib/cydia`

`/var/log/syslog`

`/var/tmp/cydia.log`

`/bin/bash`

`/bin/sh`

`/usr/sbin/sshd`

`/usr/libexec/ssh-keysign`

`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

`/etc/apt`

Most check for Cydia related files.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest looking for files that aren't present on a "vanilla" iPhone.  All jailbreak kits I've seen install ssh.  That might be a good indicator of a jailbroken phone.

Comment: ssh is never installed automatically, users must install it themselves.

Comment: I haven't really kept up with the jailbreak scene.  But as I recall, when I wrote this (Jan '09), Ziphone and others installed ssh and the bsd subsystem by default.  Perhaps that's no longer true.

Comment: trust me when i say that chpwn has kept up with the jailbreak scene.

Answer (score 3):

What we did is, we already have an RSS feed to communicate with our users ([Stocks Live](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stocks-live-portfolio-manager/id473206441?mt=8)), we put a news item that states something like this:

> Some jailbroken devices have problems bla bla bla, we made a hack to solve those issues but we need to know if this a jailbroken device or not, press here so the app fixes the issue. If you ever return to normal, ie removed the jailbreak, press here.

Then you process the user interaction and do what is appropriate, like behaving different etc...

Answer (score 3):

Try to find a file which cydia or jailbroken device create. Or try to write in a file outside the app's blackbox. If you succeed to do that, the device is compromised/jailbroken :)

```
- (BOOL)jailbroken
{
    NSFileManager * fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    return [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:@"/private/var/lib/apt/"];
}
```

Comment: Apple approved your app which contains the above code ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solutions:
Step 1

```
extension UIDevice {
    func isJailBroken() -> Bool {
        let cydiaPath = "/Applications/Cydia.app"
        let aptPath = "/private/var/lib/apt/"
        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: cydiaPath) || FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: aptPath) {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

Step 2: Call it inside `viewDidLoad()` inside your launch screen view controller(or whatever VC you are calling for the first time):

```
       // show a blank screen or some other view controller
       let viewController = UIDevice.current.isJailBroken() ? JailBrokenViewController() : NextViewController()
       self.navigationController?.present(viewController, animated: true, completion:nil)
```