# Can I identify a jailbroken phone from the crash logs?

Tags: ios, iphone, jailbreak, crash-reports

A number of the hardest to track-down problems I've come across with my iPhone application have only exposed themselves on jailbroken handsets. Is there a way to detect these handsets looking only at the crash logs?

This is kind of like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413242/how-do-i-detect-that-an-sdk-app-is-running-on-a-jailbroken-phone) but after the event rather than during...

Comment: I've upvoted all the answers (as they're all good suggestions) but have not accepted any one since there appears not to be a complete solution.

Answer (score 4):

While it certainly isn't a foolproof solution, you can look at the running binaries to see if there are jail-broken apps running at the time of the crash.  `Winterboard`, for example, is an app that only exists on jail-broken devices. If you suspect a crash is happening on a jail-broken device, I would start by inspecting there.

Answer (score 2):

you could also look for 3rd party app installers as well.  Most jail-broken devices have those to load apps more easily. I would create a small list of apps that might trigger an 'aha!' moment, that way you will at least be positive it is jail-broken

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of is mobilesubstrate prints to the console a lot and 99.99% of jailbroken phones should have it installed by default and it usually notifies you when it hooks a phones function

Answer (score 1):

One clear sign for a jailbroken device is the string `MobileSubstrate` in the crash report. Probably, there are jailbroken devices not having that string, though.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out...

http://www.iwillapps.com/wordpress/?p=70

Does Apple's crash logs include any information you NSLog? If so, just NSLog something if the app is cracked using the method in the link above!

Good luck!