# How to build an iPhone app, make sure this app only run on a no Jailbreak device?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am an iPhone developer, I am doing a project. For security reasons, I must make sure my app run on a no jailbreak iPhone. I want to know how to check it use public API.

Thanks very much!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I detect that an SDK app is running on a jailbroken phone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413242/how-do-i-detect-that-an-sdk-app-is-running-on-a-jailbroken-phone)

Comment: See also [What does jailbreak do to the iPhone technically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668867/what-does-jailbreak-do-to-the-iphone-technically)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

also, Apple removed the API for detecting jailbreaking. Read [here](http://arstechnica.com/apple/news/2010/12/jailbreak-detection-api-mysteriously-disappears-in-ios-42.ars) on ars

Answer (score 1):

No API exists to perform such a check.

Jailbreaking a device (using any of the various forms of jailbreaking) only needs to touch files which are outside an application's sandbox. Attempting to inspect them therefore carries a risk that your app will be rejected. Even if you can inspect them you have no way to differentiate a change due to jailbreaking from a change due to an OS update.

Finally please be aware that a jailbroken device does not necessarily mean the user has pirated your app. Users of jailbroken devices are free to purchase and install apps via iTunes just like anyone else and are likely to be rightly unhappy if your app refuses to run.

Answer (score 0):

If that would be possible using a public API, there wouldn't be any problem using jailbreaked iPhones, would there. Every app (including the OS) could just use that API...

Answer (score 0):

It's *impossible* to verify that your app is running only on a non-jailbroken device. Unfortunately there's nothing you can check.

There are a few tricks you can use to determine programmatically if your app has been pirated, but they're far from foolproof; the most you can really do is determine if your app was pirated using the most common automated pirating techniques. Anyone really determined to pirate it can ensure your app doesn't know it's been pirated even if you use the techniques.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't invest time in such things cause sooner or later "they" will find a way to run your App on a jailbreaked iOS device.
Instead take this time and develop more unique feature. Feature people are glad to have and even they pirated your App they will pay for it. 
Yeah I know this sounds ridiculous but I think quality software will find honest buyers.

I know this answer doesn't answer your question and I want to add that iOS doesn't have a API to check if the device is jailbroken.

I hope I could help.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers say, there's no full-proof way of blocking piracy on your apps. I have a couple of apps that have been pirated and, truth be told, I was kind of happy to see that. Unless these people hack every single app on the App Store, it made me feel a little proud that someone had decided my apps were worth pirating. Almost a "yup, I've made it" kind of feeling. :)