# how to install app in only non jailbroken devices(iPhone/iPad) but not in jailbroken devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have the requirement that user want to install the app in only non-jail-broken device.if device(iPhone/i Pad) is jail Broken it couldn't  install in device.i don't have any idea how to do this?

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: -1 **you definitely should not do this,** it is discrimination towards whom who jailbreak their device, and you also confuse piracy and cracking with jailbreaking. They are not even remotely the same!

Comment: +1 just to negate this rediculous downwote. This site is about discussing solutions to programming challenges. It is not about disussing personal opinions about legal issues or what is right or what is wrong. He has got the requirement of excluding jailbroken devices. His reasoning is none of our business.

Answer (score 1):

It s not possible. You cant do it.

Answer (score 1):

you can not avoid the installation, but you can prevent the app to run in a jailbroken device, see [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6530364/how-to-detect-that-the-app-is-running-on-a-jailbroken-device) and the accepted answer.

Comment: The link in that answer regard the app itself being cracked. It is possible to install an un-cracked app via the official app store on a jailbroken device.

Comment: If you follow the next link though, you get another way.