# Identify jailbroken device from iOS application

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak, identify

I am developing an iPhone application which is used for business purposes and it is storing many number of records in SQlite database. So my client don't want the app to run on the jailbroken devices.

So how to identify the jail broken devices during the app launch and preventing the user from proceeding further by showing some message.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6530364/how-to-detect-that-the-app-is-running-on-a-jailbroken-device

Comment: Thanks, I will make a try...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can detect through code that if the app is running on a jail broken device or not. 
Through that way you can pop up a alert and close the app. 
You can do whatever you want to do.

Here is a tutorial for it.

[Detection](http://thwart-ipa-cracks.blogspot.com/2008/11/detection.html)

```
NSString *filePath = @"/Applications/Cydia.app";
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath])
{
   // do something useful
}
```

Also if you want complete solution you can see in tapjoy sdk code.

They are detecting jailbroken iphone.

Here is tapjoy URL [tapjoy](https://www.tapjoy.com/)

Comment: Thanks for immediate response and i will try this...

Comment: Grt Tarun..+1 for nice ans

Comment: Good answer but incomplete. This code will check if Cydia application is installed on the device, so yes, if Cydia is installed it's mean the device is jailbroken but the opposite is not true : It's not because Cydia is not installed that the device is not jailbroken. A device can be jailbroken without Cydia being installed.

Comment: Hi Ashbay, that's fine. Any other suggestions on how to detect jailbroken devices in all the scenario?

Comment: And this method won't work if user install some jb-hide plugin such as Xcon.

Comment: Don't use fileExistsAtPath only, try more c methods such as stat. It will cost more effort to hook the output.