# Is ok to check if an iOS device is jailbroken without violating Apple's coding standards?

Tags: ios

Is ok to check if an iOS device is jailbroken without violating Apple's coding standards? I know there are many suggestions on how to check if an app is jailbroken. But I wanted to make sure if this does or does not break any of the apple's coding standards or sandbox guidelines.

Comment: Why do you need to check for a jailbroken device? There is a huge difference between a device that is jailbroken and your app being pirated.

Comment: Its not about piracy  I have some security concerns for my app so I was thinking of quitting the app if some one tries to run it on a jailbroken device. Is it ok to do that? This is where I read about how to detect if a device is jailbroken http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6530364/how-to-detect-that-the-app-is-running-on-a-jailbroken-device . My question if this ok under apple's standards?

Comment: No, you can't cripple an app just because the device is jailbroken. The user paid for your app. You have no right to cripple it.

Comment: @rmaddy Some banking apps that passed app store approval fail to run on JB devices.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is about App Store compliance, not a coding issue. Please see [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic for Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/175701)

Comment: Crashlytics has a check, so yes.

Comment: It is completely possible to want to not run on jailbroken devices even if you app is free. This might not make sense to your business but it does make sense to some businesses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is and there are many reasons to do so. I did this multiple times and they all passed the store approval process. Maybe there are ways that can break Apple's guidelines but it's not forbidden to check the filesystem for bash or something like this.