# how to check if an iPhone is jailbroked or not in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to prevent a user to fake the GPS coordinate, there is an app that can be run to fake the GPS if the iPhone is jailbroken. so to prevent this issue I want to check if the user is jailbroken or not, if the user uses the jailbroken iPhone, I will force close the app.

how to do that in Swift ? I can't find it in stackoverflow so far

Comment: Did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413242/how-do-i-detect-that-an-ios-app-is-running-on-a-jailbroken-phone ?

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6530364/how-to-detect-that-the-app-is-running-on-a-jailbroken-device

Comment: Just a question because i found that interesting, isn't the ""jailbroke-detection system"" hardware related ? In my opinion it would be pretty insecure, to say the least, if it was soft oriented.

Answer (score -2):

This [Jailbreak medium article](https://medium.com/@pinmadhon/how-to-check-your-app-is-installed-on-a-jailbroken-device-67fa0170cf56) provided a very good rundown

```
if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR != 1

{

// Check 1 : existence of files that are common for jailbroken devices

if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: “/Applications/Cydia.app”)

|| FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: “/Library/MobileSubstrate/MobileSubstrate.dylib”)

|| FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: “/bin/bash”)

|| FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: “/usr/sbin/sshd”)

|| FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: “/etc/apt”)

|| FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: “/private/var/lib/apt/”)

|| UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string:”cydia://package/com.example.package”)!)

{

return true

}

// Check 2 : Reading and writing in system directories (sandbox violation)

let stringToWrite = “Jailbreak Test”

do

{

try stringToWrite.write(toFile:”/private/JailbreakTest.txt”, atomically:true, encoding:String.Encoding.utf8)

//Device is jailbroken

return true

}catch

{

return false

}

}else

{

return false

}
```