# Flurry Analytics Jailbroken Detection

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, jailbreak

Flurry Analytics does Jailbroken detection. How do they do it? I know Apple pulled the APIs they had some time ago.
Regards,
Vance

EDIT: I know about: [How do I detect that an iOS app is running on a jailbroken phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413242/how-do-i-detect-that-an-sdk-app-is-running-on-a-jailbroken-phone)

The question here is how Flurry does this, NOT how to do jailbroken detection in general.

Comment: I still don't have the answer