# Once jailbroken, will iOS apps run with root privilege?

Tags: ios, xcode, jailbreak, root

Once an iOS device is jailbroken, we can build jailbreak apps (with theos) and it gets installed in the `/Applications` directory where the preloaded apps run with root privileges. If an app is built with Xcode, once it is installed, it gets into the `/private/var/mobile/Applications/` folder, which is supposed to have Apple sandbox enforced (before jailbreak).

So, the questions I have are:

1. For a jailbroken device, will the apps in `/private/var/mobile/Applications/` execute with root privileges or with `mobile` user privileges?
2. In case of Android, once rooted, the apps will have to gain root privileges by executing the `su` command. Is it the case when it comes to iOS as well?

I would like to understand the difference between these two development options (Theos / Xcode) and how it affects what operations my app can perform.

Comment: This question should not be considered off topic.  The privileges an app runs with affects which operations it can successfully complete (opening/writing files, etc.).  The steps to affect the app's privileges, as shown in **both** answers below, are not merely *sysadmin* tasks.  The source **code**, launch script, and maybe the Info.plist file, also need to be modified, which is a programmer task, implemented via Objective-C/C and shell **code**.

Comment: Wait why wouldn't `su`  work on a jailbroken iOS device?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not disagreeing with anything [H2CO3 said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15968998/119114), but to add some further clarification ...

- Apps installed in `/private/var/mobile/Applications/`(†) with Xcode will run with user `mobile` privileges, even on jailbroken phones.
- Even on a jailbroken phone, apps installed to `/private/var/mobile/Applications/`(†) will be sandboxed *almost* (‡) like apps on a jailed phone.  So, no reading other (normal) apps' data, even if those files are owned by user `mobile`.
- For a good description of the process that apps like Cydia use to run as root, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8796556/119114).  Or, just ssh into your phone, and take a look inside `/Applications/Cydia.app/` yourself.
- If you simply copy/install an app (without doing what [H2CO3 suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15968998/119114)) to `/Applications/`, it won't be sandboxed, but it will still run with `mobile` (UID=501) privileges:

```sh
iPhone5:~ root# cd /Applications

iPhone5:/Applications root# ls -altr ./HelloJB.app/
total 220
-rw-r--r--  1 root wheel   711 Apr  3 20:36 entitlements.xml
-rw-r--r--  1 root wheel   297 Apr  3 20:36 entitlements-daemon.xml
-rw-r--r--  1 root wheel  7972 Apr  3 20:36 embedded.mobileprovision
-rw-r--r--  1 root wheel 58755 Apr  3 20:36 date.zip
-rw-r--r--  1 root wheel   485 Apr  3 20:36 ResourceRules.plist
-rw-r--r--  1 root wheel     8 Apr  3 20:36 PkgInfo
-rw-r--r--  1 root wheel  1226 Apr  3 20:36 Info.plist
-rw-r--r--  1 root wheel 10960 Apr  3 20:36 Icon\@2x.png
-rw-r--r--  1 root wheel  8328 Apr  3 20:36 Icon.png
-rw-r--r--  1 root wheel   451 Apr  3 20:36 HelloJB.plist
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root wheel 61088 Apr  3 20:36 HelloJB*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root wheel 42688 Apr  3 20:36 HelloDaemon*
drwxr-xr-x  2 root wheel   136 Apr  3 20:36 en.lproj/
drwxr-xr-x  2 root wheel   102 Apr  3 20:36 _CodeSignature/
drwxr-xr-x  4 root wheel   544 Apr  3 20:36 ./
drwxrwxr-x 54 root admin  1904 Apr  5 02:14 ../

iPhone5:/Applications root# ps -Aef | grep HelloJB
  501  9412     1   0   0:00.00 ??         0:00.33 /Applications/HelloJB.app/HelloJB

iPhone5:/Applications root# grep mobile /etc/passwd
mobile:*:501:501:Mobile User:/var/mobile:/bin/sh
```

(‡) Here's a [good discussion, with input from Saurik, about how different jailbreaks may affect the sandbox](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=4127801).  Long story short: it depends.

---

**(†) Update**: in recent versions of iOS, the location of 3rd-party apps has been moved to `/var/mobile/Containers`, and later to `/var/containers/`, but the same basic sandbox issues remain.

Answer (score 8):

Long story short: no.

**Jailbreaking is a necessary but not sufficient condition for gaining root.** Apps will still be sandboxed by default.

What you can do for making your app run with root privileges is creating a startup shell script that has `root:wheel` ownership and `755` permissions, then create your actual executable with the same ownership, `7555` as permissions (i. e. set its "setuid" bit), then call `setuid(0);` from within `main()`, before calling `UIApplicationMain()`.