# iOS 6.0 and up to max : How can i give root access to my own application. iPhone is jailbreak

Tags: iphone, ios, sms, root, jailbreak

I am new in iPhone.I am developing iPhone application. My iPhone is jailbreak, I want to use a message history from my jailbreak device. But i can't used that message history. So I want to give root access permission to my application for access SMS history. How can I do it, How can I give root permission to my application. Thank You for your answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Once jailbroken, will iOS apps run with root privilege?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15968845/once-jailbroken-will-ios-apps-run-with-root-privilege)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Gaining root permissions on iOS for NSFileManager (Jailbreak)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841344/gaining-root-permissions-on-ios-for-nsfilemanager-jailbreak)

Answer (score 0):

After compiling, unzip the ipa and drop the .app folder in "Payload" into /Applications. Now run `chmod -R 777 /Applications/<YourAppName>` This should get rid of Apple's sandbox and let you take advantage of your jailbreak. You might even want to consider packaging it into a .deb file so that others can install it like this automatically.