# launchctl not working from iOS App

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode5, jailbreak

i am trying to stop and start com.apple.mobile.installd from my app which is for jailbroken phone. i tried almost every possible way NSTask, system(), shell script but its not working. can someone help me out??

below are my code samples i tried.

```
-(IBAction)stopIntl:(id)sender
{
    NSString *command = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/bin/launchctl stop com.apple.mobile.installd >> /Applications/loader.app/output.txt"];
    const char* new = [command UTF8String];
    system(new);
    NSLog(@"Stopping InstallD");
}

-(IBAction)startIntl:(id)sender
{
    NSString *command = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/bin/launchctl start com.apple.mobile.installd >> /Applications/loader.app/output.txt"];
    const char* new = [command UTF8String];
    system(new);
    NSLog(@"Starting InstallD");
}

-(IBAction)reloadShell:(id)sender
{
    system("/bin/launchctl stop com.apple.mobile.installd");
    sleep(2);
    system("/bin/launchctl start com.apple.mobile.installd");

    NSLog(@"Reloading Shell");
}

-(IBAction)reloadShell1:(id)sender
{
    NSString *command = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/usr/libexec/reload.sh >> /Applications/loader.app/output.txt"];
    system([command UTF8String]);
    NSLog(@"Reloading Shell1");
}
```

my reload.sh it works from terminal..

```
#!/bin/sh

#  reload.sh
#
#  Copyright (c) 2014 Avanté Codeworx. All #rights reserved.

launchctl stop com.apple.mobile.installd
sleep 2
launchctl start com.apple.mobile.installd
exit
```

bangging my head since last ten days, Also tried Launch Daemon it works but keeps on running.. never goes down..

Here is my daemon..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>LaunchEvents</key>
    <dict>
        <key>com.apple.notifyd.matching</key>
        <dict>
            <key>com.loader.reload</key>
            <dict>
                <key>Notification</key>
                <string>com.loader.reload</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.avante.loader</string>
    <key>UserName</key>
    <string>root</string>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <false/>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/usr/libexec/reload.sh</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Please help me out!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a misconception some people have.

Just because your phone is jailbroken, [apps don't run with root privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15970080/119114).

Just because your app is installed in `/Applications/`, it won't run with `root` privileges.

To cause your app to run with `root` privileges, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8796556/119114).  Otherwise, it will run as user `mobile`.

`launchctl` needs `root` privileges to function properly.

P.S. *And, of course, you can remove the launch daemon.  The proper way to do it is simply to give your app root privileges.*

Comment: I solved it two days ago.. but accidentally.. it was a good clarification for what i did. Thanks!!