# Compile Xcode Application directly into /Applications?

Tags: ios, root, jailbreak

Is it possible to directly compile ios apps from Xcode directly into the /Applications folder and get root access? Yes, my iDevice is jailbroken. I need to have root access to correctly work with my app.

Comment: I believe THEOS can do this, but I've never used it before.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Me neither, but isn't there an easy way for xcode?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the app into /Applications manually (using SSH/iFile/another explorer), and make it run as root in a few steps :

- In your YourAppName.app folder, rename the executable, originally named YourAppName, into something else
- Then create a file named YourAppName, edit it and type the following :

`#!/bin/bash`
`dir=$(dirname "$0")`
`exec "${dir}"/YourRenamedExecutable "$@"`

When you'll run the app, the little script above will be run and launch your app as root

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do this if you install the [iOSOpenDev](http://iosopendev.com) toolset, which gives you a customized Xcode installation.

iOSOpenDev uses Xcode build phase scripts to install your app (bundled as a .deb package) on the device.  It should install it under `/Applications/` by default.

[Read more here](https://github.com/kokoabim/iOSOpenDev/wiki/SSH-Public-Key-Authentication)

*Note: just because your app is installed in `/Applications/`, it [will not automatically have root privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15970080/119114).*

Comment: Thanks for pointing me towards iOSOpenDev. I'll take a look at it.