# prevent fake in app purchase on jailbroken device

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6, in-app-purchase

I am working on a project, in which I have included consumable In-App purchase. Now on jailbroken device, user can make fake in-app purchase. I have already included Receipt Verification code

How to prevent it ? Is there anything I am missing here ? Is it possible to check a device is jailbroken or not ?

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413242/how-do-i-detect-that-an-sdk-app-is-running-on-a-jailbroken-phone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is possible know if your app are running in a jailbroken device, most of all jailbroken devices have an app called **Cydia**, you can check if this app exist:

```
+(BOOL)isJailbroken {
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"cydia://package/com.example.package"];
return [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url];
}
```

Cydia has a URL scheme cydia:// which can be legally checked with UIApplication canOpenURL:

Comment: This is not a definitive way.  It is *pretty good* but not perfect.  Furthermore, just because a device is jailbroken does not mean that the user is malicious.  That is a more dangerous assumption.

Comment: Note that not all users have Cydia installed -- this is not a good check, and you should rather check for something like /bin/bash that /all/ users /will/ have.