# Prevent installation of iOS app in jail broken devices

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, jailbreak

I want to prevent installation of my iOS app in jail broken devices. Is there any checks that can be done during installation to identitfy if the device is jail broken ? Is there any way to stop the installation if the device is jail broken?

Comment: The first problem is how to determine if an iOS device is jail broken.

Comment: You cannot control the installation process - Your app is installed by the installer that is part of iOS.  You can try and detect a jailbroken device when your app runs and take some action - display a message and refuse to go any further perhaps

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks. But is there any way to programatically delete the app from the device?

Comment: No, there isn't.  Also if they have jailbroken the device then they can copy the app from another device and bypass the Apple installer as well.

Comment: Why do you want to stop your app on a jailbroken device?

Comment: @rmaddy client requirement.

Answer (score 8):

Generally, it break down to two questions:

1) Detection of a jailbreak device.

There are plenty of different methods. None of them is 100% guaranteed to work.
Look at this question:
[How do I detect that an iOS app is running on a jailbroken phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413242/how-do-i-detect-that-an-ios-app-is-running-on-a-jailbroken-phone)

2) Taking some actions on a jailbroken device

As @Paulw11 mentioned, you can't stop installation and you can't uninstall.

The common way is just exit from your application (don't provide any useful functionality to a user). However, if your application have very high value, this protection can be removed by somebody who will reverse engineer your application.

Generally speaking, there is no bulletproof protection, but you can make it good enough, so it won't be worthwhile breaking it.