# Limiting beta installations to specific UDIDs

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm about to make a little beta test for my iOS project. A few people will send me their UDIDs, I will add them to my distribution provisioning profile, then upload a build containing such profile for them to install through iTunes.

I have heard that a non-tester, whose UDID is NOT in the profile of my build, is still capable of installing the .IPA I upload. Probably with a jailbroken device, Cydia or something like that.

Is there a way to avoid this? To truly limit the installations to specific UDIDs, even against jailbroken devices?

Comment: You can slow them down. Check [how](http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Bypassing_Jailbreak_Detection) the jailbreakers bypass the usual protections, and adapt to that. The key take away is that if they are really motivated you can't stop them. You should make it hard enough to crack (check code signature, obfuscate a C function `detect_jailbreak()`, etc) to discourage script kiddies.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method to avoid you Application to run on jailbroken device. But I would prefer to upload the build to testflightapp.com and do your beta-test over there. I am very happy with there service and you testers don't have to install the app via iTunes.

Comment: But when you upload it to TestFlight, they can still get the .IPA separately can't they?

Comment: They can, if they have the direct link to it or if some of your testers send them the .ipa.
Just build this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413242/how-do-i-detect-that-an-ios-app-is-running-on-a-jailbroken-phone
in you application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: and wirte an exit(1); in there so that jailbroken devices can't open the app.