# How to make iOS application tamper-evident?

Tags: ios, security, monitor, tampering

I am working on a project (mobile app) where I need to monitor adversary actions. So, my question is how can I make iOS app tamper-evident?

e.g.

- Whenever any adversary try to tamper code then system should alert admin for these actions
- and block that adversary
- If user tries to install app on rooted device then system can detect that.
- System should able to monitor adversary actions.

I found solution for android like `ProGuard`, `SafetyNet` but did not found anything for iOS.

Comment: Normally i would think along the lines of creating MD5 checksums over the files. Which you then check periodically, to see if they have changed. Since IOS all apps are sandboxed, I doubt you can access any files (outside your app).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413242/how-do-i-detect-that-an-ios-app-is-running-on-a-jailbroken-phone

Comment: *Pekka 웃* gives you a link to a popular similar question on Dec 1 '16. Next day, on Dec 2 '16, *itechnician* copy-pastes a one-year-old answer from that similar question WITHOUT CREDITING THE AUTHOR, and yet you grant it a +100 bounty?

Answer (score 9):

I've used this [JailBreak detection](https://github.com/thii/DTTJailbreakDetection) in one of my project.

With this, you can prevent the possibility.

```
    if ([DTTJailbreakDetection isJailbroken]) {

// your custom activity and business logic here
    }
```

Also, In precise you can use the below [snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26712383):

```
BOOL isJailbroken()
{
#if !(TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR)

   if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:@"/Applications/Cydia.app"] ||
       [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:@"/Library/MobileSubstrate/MobileSubstrate.dylib"] ||
       [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:@"/bin/bash"] ||
       [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:@"/usr/sbin/sshd"] ||
       [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:@"/etc/apt"] ||
       [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:@"/private/var/lib/apt/"] ||
       [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"cydia://package/com.example.package"]])  {
         return YES;
   }

   FILE *f = NULL ;
   if ((f = fopen("/bin/bash", "r")) ||
      (f = fopen("/Applications/Cydia.app", "r")) ||
      (f = fopen("/Library/MobileSubstrate/MobileSubstrate.dylib", "r")) ||
      (f = fopen("/usr/sbin/sshd", "r")) ||
      (f = fopen("/etc/apt", "r")))  {
         fclose(f);
         return YES;
   }
   fclose(f);

   NSError *error;
   NSString *stringToBeWritten = @"This is a test.";
   [stringToBeWritten writeToFile:@"/private/jailbreak.txt" atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
   [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:@"/private/jailbreak.txt" error:nil];
   if(error == nil)
   {
      return YES;
   }

#endif

   return NO;
}
```

Also , [Obfuscation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_(software)) in iOS - objective C you can use this [open source-library](https://github.com/obfuscator-llvm/obfuscator/wiki) and for [Methods & Classes](https://github.com/Polidea/ios-class-guard).

Comment: any official documentation for backing `DTTJailbreakDetection`?

Comment: Please check the github link . i added

Comment: Please check the obfuscation reference too for your perusal.

Answer (score 4):

Apart from detecting jailbroken device, and obfuscating code (as @itechnician mentioned), you can:

- Detect if debugger is attached: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1361/_index.html
- Check the load commands in Mach-O header to check if there's anything injected
- Check code integrity

Anyway, all of these can be easily bypassed when on jailbroken device (even the check if it's jailbroken). The best way is to use multiple techniques including obfuscation, to make tampering as hard as possible (so it's not worth it). But I'm not sure if you could make fully tamper-proof app.

You might find these links useful:

https://www.coredump.gr/articles/ios-anti-debugging-protections-part-1/
https://www.raywenderlich.com/45645/ios-app-security-analysis-part-1
http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/ios-application-security-part-31-problem-using-third-party-libraries-securing-apps/

This book is a bit old, but still useful: http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920023234.do

Here are opensource ObjC obfuscators/string encryptors:

- https://github.com/Polidea/ios-class-guard
- https://github.com/FutureWorkshops/Objc-Obfuscator
- https://github.com/pjebs/Obfuscator-iOS

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking something like [ixguard](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/ixguard)

Comment: is it a paid service? I am more interested in some open-source solution.

Comment: Yes it is a paid service. I dont think there is an open source solution completely covers what you need.

Comment: Tamper and jailbreak detection are not (yet) part of iXGuard today.